# Access a file in a Zend way

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-io

I've looked around alot for a way to access a file in Zend using the framework instead of just writing my own php access stuff, but I'm not having any luck. 
Is there a Zend way to do read a file?

Comment: Is there a particular type of file you are trying to access? Reading and Writing files is pretty primitive, and not much is gained by offering an abstraction without a clear goal as to what you are trying to accomplish with the abstraction.

Comment: well, I'm going to need to read and edit json, csv, xml, and 2 other non-standard text based file extensions. Unfortuatenly I don't get the choice of a database, and info gets put into several different files